# How to set break point sql server 2008 for trigger

Tags: sql-server-2008

Hi i have large size trigger.so i have to check whether values are passed to trigger or not.so how to set break point for trigger in sql server 2008.

Comment: Why can't you just use `PRINT` and observe the output?

Comment: The only values passed to the trigger are those in the inserted and deleted pseudo_tables.  As far as I am aware, text and ntext fields (Which you should no longer be usingas they are deprecated) do not go into inserted or deleted.